# Should glfwDestroyWindow always be called?

Tags: c++, c, glfw

I've recently found GLFW and have been trying out making a simple application with it and was wondering about glfwTerminate and glfwDestroyWindow. I understand that glfwTerminate will cleanup any windows that are still open so it should be safe to never call gflwDestroyWindow on the main window but should I still call gflwDestroyWindow before terminating or is it more just a personal preference?

To clarify which of the following are "better".

```
auto window = glfwCreateWindow(...);
// Do some things
glfwDestroyWindow(window);
glfwTerminate();
```

Or

```
auto window = glfwCreateWindow(...);
// Do some things
glfwTerminate();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html)

> All windows remaining when `glfwTerminate` is called are destroyed as well.

you don't need to do call `glfwDestroyWindow(window);`. Although I suppose it is better to destroy each window separately.